# Capitalization of "Grant"

Tags: nouns, acronyms

Should grant be capitalized in this sentence? I don't know the rule that to apply to ensure I'm writing correctly. CS = Community Safety. I've provided two examples.

A representative from the Office of Field Operations conducted a technical review of the **CS Grant** applications.

A representative from PHMSA’s Office of Field Operations conducted a technical review of the **CS grant** applications.

---

We recommend funding for the four **CS grant** applications referenced in Attachment 1.

We recommend funding for the four **CS Grant** applications referenced in Attachment 1.

Comment: Is 'Grant' capitalised in material supplied by the Office of Field Operations?

Comment: If I was simply using the word "grant" as in, for example "We must see if there is a grant available for the project", then clearly one wouldn't capitalise - it is a common noun like any other. However as the "CS Grant" appears to be the name of something specific, I would treat it as a proper noun and give it capitals throughout. But as @MichaelHarvey suggests it might be no bad thing to look and see how their own office treat it.

Comment: Thanks. Where I find it, its inconsistent . My sense is that it makes more sense and reads better as a proper noun. Also, the Community Safety Grant is the topic of the Action Memo I'm editing.

Comment: While a memo topic takes caps for most non-capitalized words, the name of the application itself might be CS Grant Application.